# Is there a way to get Kusto explorer to make a sound once my query finishes running?

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I was wondering if there is a way to make Kusto explorer make some sort of noise once my query finishes executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *now* there is :-)
The praises go to [@alexander-sloutsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10151794/alexander-sloutsky)

Thanks for this feature suggestion!

[image: What's new?]

[image: Options]